# How to change the template which Grails uses to generate a unit test via the command `create-unit-test`?

Tags: grails, scripting

How can I change the template which Grails uses to generate a unit test via the command `create-unit-test`?
I would like e.g. to replace spaces by tabs, modify imports, remove the javadoc instruction, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running `grails install-templates` will create copies of the default templates under `src/templates` (scaffolding templates will go in `src/templates/scaffolding`, other templates will go in `src/templates/artifacts`) which you can then freely modify. The generate and create scripts and runtime dynamic scaffolding will prefer your app's templates over the default ones.